# Can we predict the inflation rate in India for the next 20 years?

Tags: inflation

Can we predict the inflation rate in India for the next 20 years?

Like inflation rate in 2022, 2023, 2024... and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially you can predict inflation in any country for arbitrary number of years if you just care about having *some* predictions, regardless of forecasting accuracy.

Generally speaking, forecasting errors increase with time. So no matter what forecasting model you use it will become very inaccurate for predicting inflation in latter time periods.

Professional forecasters (for example at central bank) usually stick to 1 year or maximum 5 year forecasting predictions for inflation. Usually already after 1 year forecasts start to be inaccurate and after 5 years they are usually too inaccurate to be of any use.